# Nodemailer with Mailgun

Tags: node.js, email, express, mailgun, nodemailer

I am trying to send out emails when a user signs up to my site. I decided on Nodemailer and MailGun and have come to realize there is not many tutorials or good docs on them working together. Seems to be a similar issue for the rest of the services like MailGun. Below is my code for an attempt at getting it to work. I watched a tutorial on getting it to work but cant seem to figure it out. I think the code is right but maybe the auth is wrong? Or I could just be off on both. I am using cloud9.io for my dev environment so maybe that is the issue? Or that my domain is not verified yet?

Route:

```
app.post('/signup',
    setRedirect({auth: '/dashboard', success: '/dashboard', failure: '/signup'}),
    isUnauthenticated,
    registrations.postSignup,
    (req, res) =>{
      const output = `
        <h1>Your email is: ${req.body.email}</h1>
         `;

      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'postmaster@MYSUBDOMAIN',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'postmaster@MYSUBDOMAIN', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'MYPASSWORD'  // generated ethereal password
        },
        tls:{
          rejectUnauthorized:false
        }
      });

      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
          from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <your@email.com>', // sender address
          to: '`${req.body.email}`', // list of receivers
          subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
          text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
          html: output // html body
      };

      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
          console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

          // render view here and pass in data/message
      });
    });
```

Then the domain information from mailgun.com:

```
State
Unverified
IP Address
IPASSIGNED Manage IPs
SMTP Hostname
smtp.mailgun.org
Default SMTP Login
postmaster@MYSUBDOMAIN
API Base URL
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MYSUBDOMAIN
Default Password
MYPASSWORD SMTP credentials
API Key
MYKEY
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show any errors that you are getting

Comment: @Mikkel I posted the answer to this question already. I can't reasonably go back and get the errors unless I break my code again. Answer is there with an explanation. Also the error was just referencing an express file nothing else. It was quite useless to be honest. Anyways I got it fixed and others can see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured I should update this answer to show the differences. I changed the port from `587` to `2525` because I am using cloud 9 which is hosted on Google's servers and they have port `587` blocked but allow `2525` for SMTP. Secondly I changed the `to` email to a variable I set to `req.body.email` which is the new user's email. My form doesn't have their name since it is for a) companies b) that is more friction to signing up and will slightly lower conversion rates. If your form has their name use that in the template string where I used their email again.

```
app.post('/signup',
    setRedirect({auth: '/dashboard', success: '/dashboard', failure: '/signup'}),
    isUnauthenticated,
    registrations.postSignup,
    (req, res) =>{
      var newUserEmail = req.body.email;
      const output = `
        <h1>Your email is: ${req.body.email}</h1>
      `;

      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
        port: 2525,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'postmaster@MYSUBDOMAIN', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'MYPASSWORD'  // generated ethereal password
        },
        tls:{
          rejectUnauthorized:false
        }
      });

      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
          from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <your@email.com>', // sender address
          to: newUserEmail, // list of receivers
          subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
          text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
          html: output // html body
      };

      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   

          // render view here and pass in data/message
      });
    });
```